# Why do I keep getting an empty table when I run this program?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

This is what I have written. I'm guessing it might be something with the logic of my `while` loop, but I can't quite spot it! Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

//Open main function.
int main(void)
{
    double new_area, area_total = 14000, area_uncut = 2500, rate = 0.02, years;
    int count = 0;

    printf("This program is written for a plot of land totaling 14000 acres,    "
           "with 2500 acres of uncut forest\nand a reforestation rate "
           "of 0.02. Given a time period (years) this program will output a table\n"
           "displaying the number acres reforested at the end of "
           "each year.\n\n\n");

    printf("Please enter a value of 'years' to be used for the table.\n"
           "Values presented will represent the number acres reforested at the end of "
           "each year:>> ");

    scanf("%lf", &years);

    years = ceil(years);

    printf("\n\nNumber of Years\t\tReforested Area");

    while (count <= years);
    {
        count = count + 1;
        new_area = area_uncut + (rate * area_uncut);
        printf("\n%1.0lf\t\t\t%.1lf", count, area_uncut);
        area_uncut += new_area;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where does it stop in the program..... does it even go into the while loop? Add some other print statements and debug it that way

Comment: `printf("\n%1.0lf\t\t\t%.1lf",count,area_uncut);` you print  an `int` (`count`)  using `%lf`, this is undefined behaviour (change to `%d`).

Comment: `while (count <= years);` -- the `;` there creates an empty loop body. Turn on full warnings in your compiler, it should warn about this.

Comment: @Barmar, why a warning?, it seems legal (useless but legal)

Comment: @KeineLust That's why it's a warning, not an error. It's a common typo, and the compiler warns in case it's not what you really meant.

Comment: What flag are you enabling to receive such warning?

Comment: @Barmar: I compiled with `g++` and `-Wall` and it did not show up. I still upvoted your comment because removing that semicolon fixes OPs issue. When I try to compile with `gcc` I get an error because of the `ceil`.

Comment: @KeineLust I got it with default options on OS X, it says it comes from `-Wempty-body`

Comment: @KeineLust The warning message says "put the semicolon on a separate line to silence this warning". That's how you indicate that you wanted the useless loop.

Comment: @Keine Lust, i know for example that xcode gives a warning for cases like this

Comment: gcc is ignoring this flag on Linux :(

Comment: Darn! Silly mistake to include that colon. Thank-you everyone for pointing this out.

Answer (score 4):

There is an extra `;` at the end of this line: `while (count <= years);`

It is parsed as an empty body for the `while` loop, causing it to iterate forever since `count` is not updated at all.

Here is a way to avoid this kind of silly mistake: use the Kernighan and Ritchie style where the `{` is at the end of the line start controlling the block:

```
while (count <= years) {
    count = count + 1;
    new_area = area_uncut + (rate * area_uncut);
    printf("\n%d\t\t\t%.1f", count, area_uncut);
    area_uncut += new_area;
}
```

With this style, an extra `;` is much less likely to by typed and would be much easier to spot as incongruous.

Also note that `count` was defined as `int`, so the `printf` format was incorrect too.  Definitely compile with more warnings enabled.